# EM algorithm interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, optimization, expectation-maximization

I have question on EM algorithm derivation,
in the typical EM algorithm from Andrew ng's slides http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes8.pdf. assuming x is observable, z is latent variable

in E step: $$Q(z) = p(z|x;\theta)$$
in M step: we do $$\arg\max_\theta \sum_z Q(z) * \frac{\log p(x,z)}{Q(z)}$$

my question is in M step, when we replace the $Q(z)$ with $p(z|x;\theta)$, it is
$$\arg\max_\theta \sum_z p(z|x) * \log\frac{ p(x,z)}{p(z|x)}=\arg\max_\theta \sum_z p(z|x) \log p(x)$$ $$=\arg\max_\theta \log p(x) \sum_z p(z|x) = \arg\max_\theta \log p(x)$$
Then, this becomes MLE for observable. but if I derive it as the following:
$$\arg\max_\theta \sum_z p(z|x) * \log\frac{ p(x,z)}{p(z|x)}=\arg\max_\theta \sum_z p(z|x) \log p(x)$$ $$\geq \arg\max_\theta \log \sum_z p(z|x) p(x) = \arg\max_\theta \log p(x,z)$$
then this is interpret as maximum log joint probability. basically, it max MLE and joint prob. Did I make any mistakes here for two case? Thanks

Comment: I think there is one main issue in the notation of almost all lecture notes on the EM algorithm: In the EM-algo it is about having *old* parameters $\Theta^{\text{old}}$ and *new* parameters $\Theta$ and how the likelihood changes when moving from the old to the new parameters. That being said, what one does is writing $p_\Theta(x,z) = p_\Theta(x,z) \cdot \frac{p_{\Theta^\text{old}}(z|x)}{p_{\Theta^\text{old}}(z|x)}$ hence you cannot put the second terms $p(x,z)$ together with $p(z|x)$ because those distributions work on different parameters!

Comment: Further: how do you derive $\frac{\log(p(x,z))}{p(z|x)} = \log p(x)$? The numerator has a 'log' in front of it while the denominator does not...

Comment: Ah I think that your formulae are misleading because the log is in front of the whole frac everywhere. Could you check?

Comment: In the very last equation: What you get is indeed the same as above: $\sum_z p(z|x)p(x) = \sum_z \frac{p(z,x)}{p(x)}p(x) = \sum_z p(z,x) = p(x)$, no?

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I made a typo on latex...and this cause all problems. just correct it. and you are right, in that sense, the objective function for two derivation are the same. Thank you for your answer, if you could make the last comment to be answer, I will mark it

Comment: @FabianWerner one more question, so EM is actually equivalent doing MLE on observed variable, am I right here? Thanks

Comment: hmm... EM maximizes (in the parameters of the density) some (at first glance) completely unrelated quantity Q. Turns out that one can show (using Jensens inequality as you did above) that maximizing this unrelated quantity yields a somewhat maximization process for the likelihood function (including the hidden variables). Therefore it returns estimates of the parameters for the complete density in question (including the hidden variables) which is then used for prediction of the actual values of the latent variables (given the rest of the input $X_i$).

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question indicating the dependence of all relevant quantities on either the old $\theta$ used for the expectation or the free $\theta$ used for the maximisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation of the question as the M step is incorrect (and Andrew Ng does not use this equation as the M step but as an argument to show EM increases the observed likelihood at each step of the algorithm).

The correct M step is the derivation of
$$\arg\max_\theta\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,Z|x,\theta) | \theta^{(t)}]$$
where $\theta^{(t)}$ is the current value of the parameter at the $t$ iteration of the EM algorithm. This quantity writes down as
$$\arg\max_\theta\sum_{z}p(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\log p(x,z|\theta)$$
Therefore the sum involves a product of two terms, one depending on current value of the parameter at the $t$ iteration and one depending on the free parameter $\theta$, parameter involved in the maximisation.

Answer (score 0):

In the very last equation: What you get is indeed the same as above:

$$\sum_z p(z|x)p(x) = \sum_z \frac{p(z,x)}{p(x)}p(x) = \sum_z p(z,x) = p(x)$$

Comment: I love EM questions :-)))